# ASP.NET: Language specific format when binding

Tags: asp.net

I have a date TextBox that is bound to a DateTime property:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date1">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="Date1TextBox" Text='<%# Bind("Date1", "{0: yyyy-MM-dd}")%>' runat="server"/> 
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

What is the easiest way to make the format dynamic, meaning that I want to be able to specify which format I want to use dependent on the current ui culture / language. Is it possible to do this in markup (I want to avoid to do this in Code if possible)?

I tried the following but Bind doesn't seem to support methods to get the format string:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Date1TextBox" Text='<%# Bind("Date1", GetCurrentFormat())%>' runat="server"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="Date1TextBox" Text='<%# Eval("Date1","{0:yyyy-MM-dd}") %>'
runat="server"/>
```

**EDIT**

```
protected string GetCurrentFormat(string myDate)
{
 //Retrive Current Format from DB
 string MyFormat="yyyy-MM-dd";
return Convert.ToDateTime(myDate).ToString(MyFormat);
}


 <asp:TextBox ID="Date1TextBox" 
Text='<%# GetCurrentFormat(Convert.ToString(Eval("Date1"))) %>'
    runat="server"/>
```

Comment: I need two-way-binding Eval is one-way. Also you have hard-coded the format?

Comment: I think myDate has to be of type object. Also I'm still losing the client to server binding (Date1 won't be updated automatically).

Comment: @user764754 you can use `ToString` check now